# Getting an error while trying to use the bugzilla python package

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, bugzilla

I am relatively new to Python. I am encountering an error while trying to use the bugzilla python package. Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
import bugzilla
bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url="https://bugzilla.kernel.org")
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'bugzilla' has no attribute 'Bugzilla'
```

Here are the details of my environment:

PyCharm Community Edition IDE on Windows 10.
Python 3.6.3 version.

I seem to have set the Python interpreter path correctly in PyCharm as I don't have any problem in using other packages such as pandas.

I installed both the bugzilla as well as the python-bugzilla packages using pip. I get the same error in both cases. What is the difference in these two packages? Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Most likely you have a local file called `bugzilla.py` that is shadowing the package. Rename that file and all should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Bernie. I indeed had a local file called bugzilla.py. The error disappeared after I renamed the file.

Comment: Sweet. You can feel free to close the question I think :-) Have a good day!